# fast way to load ajax content

Tags: javascript, ajax

Lets say i have json which contains informations. What would be the best way to put the informations on site. Creating elements via js like
(this is just part im interested in , inside ajax call)
    var div=document.creteElement("div");
    var text=document.createTextNode("bla");
    var img=new Img;
    img.src=json1.img;
    img.onload=function(){
      div.appendChild(text);
      div.appendChild(img);
    }
or putting them "in" like

```
body.innerHTML+="<div><p>blabla</p><img src='json1.img'/></div>"`
```

which one of there is better/faster/more efficient , or is there any better way how to put content into site via ajax? Also how does big sites that load tons of data from server handle this? Tons of data would take  a lot of time to load

Comment: It does not matter - pick whatever suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I understand now. To render content from ajax you have 3 choices:

1. Load the data with an ajax request ($.ajax in jquery or xmlhttprequest from scratch) and then create elements and insert into DOM. This solution is very bad because it is unmaintainable.
2. Load data using ajax and use javascript templates like Underscore template (_.template) or Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/). This is a very useful solution.
3. Load data using ajax and use a very powerfull system views like React JS. I love it and it's very intuitive and easy to use to have a good performance without a lot of work from your part. "Template system" is very cool and easy (like using html). I will use react if I were you :) https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: how is first method unmaintainable? I mean , what makes other two methods more maintainable

Comment: Because if your app is medium/big you need to create a lot of html elements using javascript, with their attributes, values, css classes, inline styles,...., add childs to elements, ...,..., and the code would be very very big and a nightmare to maintain. Try doing step 1, then step 2 (templates) and finally react js (with templates jsx) and see which option is the best comfortable and maintenable ;)